# Redirect a WM_PAINT to default handler, replacing the DC?

Tags: winapi, atl, wtl

Given a class deriving from, say, CEdit, is it possible to intercept the WM_PAINT message, calling the base class message with a different CDC?

```
    class CEditNew : public CWindowImpl<CEditNew, CEdit>
    {
    public:

        BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CEditNew)
            MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_PAINT, OnPaint)  
        END_MSG_MAP()

        LRESULT OnPaint(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL &)
        {           
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

I can intercept the WM_PAINT of the CEdit by calling SubclassWindow but I'd really like to then call the base class original paint handler.

For context the parent window has its own compatibledc (it's using translucency) and I need to allow child controls to paint themselves when they need to by giving them this dc.

Comment: Tinkering with EDIT controls like this doesn't work, it commits a grave crime and paints without using WM_PAINT.

Comment: It's not really tinkering.  I just want it to paint to the DC I give it when it updates as it would if I used WM_PRINT or WM_PRINTCLIENT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target `HDC` is not passed in the `WM_PAINT` message itself, it is obtained from `BeginPaint()`.  You have no control over which `HDC` it returns.

The correct way to ask an `HWND` to paint itself to a specific `HDC` is to use the [`PrintWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869.aspx) function, or send it a [`WM_PRINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145216.aspx) message directly.

Comment: Yes I'm using WM_PRINTCLIENT to render the layered window and its children.  The trouble is if, for example, I attempt to add an edit box to the layered window it isn't interactive.  I can get messages from it but I don't think it's repainting itself.  I need to somehow poke the parent layered window to refresh itself if any child needs a repaint.